# Error Creating System Register Entry Error On Win8

Tags: delphi

On Windows 8, the following raises error.

```
CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED or COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY); 
// or simply CoInitialize(nil); gives the same error
```

However, if application runs as 'Administrator', it is working fine.

On Windows 7, there is no such problem.

The application is built using Delphi XE3, (32-bit).

Any solution to get rid of this?

```
First chance exception at $76AA4B32. 
Exception class EOleRegistrationError with message 
'Error creating system registry entry'. Process RPM.exe (4584)
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you told us what the error was it raised. I can't quite read your screen from where I'm sitting.

Comment: Note that `COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY` does nothing at all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/08/10366704.aspx

Comment: re-edited. It also raises exception if i use CoInitialize(nil);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you report in the question is not thrown by a call to `CoInitialize`. The error that you report is a Delphi exception and `CoInitialize` is a Windows API call. A call to `CoInitialize` will not raise a Delphi exception.

The `EOleRegistrationError` is thrown by `TComObjectFactory.UpdateRegistry`. And that method is called when you are attempting to register (or unregister) a COM server. Which is something that requires administrator rights because it involves modifications to `HKLM`.

So, it would seem that the call to `CoInitialize` is not the problem at all. The problem is that you are attempting to modify the COM registry under `HKLM` which is something that requires elevation. Naturally, when you elevate, this modification succeeds.

If your program worked on your Windows 7 machine it is most likely that the machine has UAC disabled, or the process was running elevated.

Comment: omg, you save my time a lot!. yes, you are right, the error was caused by its previous one line, somehow it stopped at the line next to the error.